# Get-process command giving negative value while monitoring process on a remote computer

Tags: powershell

I am executing this command on my system

```
get-process $Processname -computername $Computername
```

but in output its giving me negative Working set and Paged memory size value
output:

```
Name        ID         VM   PeakVM          WS         PeakWS Thread     Handle
----        --         --   ------          --         ------ ------     ------
FusionA  10724      -1282     -988       -1777          -1697    232       2085
FusionA  10724      -1281     -988       -1746          -1697    232       2091
FusionA  10724      -1280     -988       -1713          -1697    232       2099
FusionA  10724      -1279     -988       -1707          -1697    232       2108
FusionA  10724      -1277     -988       -1702          -1697    232       2118
```

Plz let me know the ways to comeover this issue..
For those who do not understand what I mean no need to to burst out plz as I am explaining it more..
Initially I am doing something like this:

```
if($env:Processor_Architecture -eq "x86")
{
write "`nrunning on 32bit"
$a = @{Expression={$_.Name.SubString(0,7)};Label="Name";width=7}, `
@{Expression={$_.ID};Label="ID";width=6}, `
@{Expression={$_.PagedMemorySize/1024};Label="VirtualMemory";width=10},
@{Expression={$_.PeakPagedMemorySize/1024};Label="PeakVirtualMemory";width=8},
@{Expression={$_.WS/1024};Label="WorkingSet";width=11},
@{Expression={$_.PeakWorkingSet/1024};Label="PeakWorkingSet";width=14},
@{Expression={$_.threads.count};Label="Threads";width=6},
@{Expression={$_.Handles};Label="Handles";width=10}

}
else
{
write "`nrunning on 64bit"
$a = @{Expression={$_.Name.SubString(0,7)};Label="Name";width=7}, `
@{Expression={$_.ID};Label="ID";width=6}, `
@{Expression={$_.PagedMemorySize64/1024};Label="VirtualMemory";width=10},
@{Expression={$_.PeakPagedMemorySize64/1024};Label="PeakVirtualMemory";width=10},
@{Expression={$_.WorkingSet64/1024};Label="WorkingSet";width=11},
@{Expression={$_.PeakWorkingSet64/1024};Label="PeakWorkingSet";width=14},
@{Expression={$_.threads.count};Label="Threads";width=6},
@{Expression={$_.Handles};Label="Handles";width=10}

}
```

After that I am running the following command:

```
get-process $Processname -computername $Computername  | format-table   $a -wrap
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following --

```
get-process $Processname -computername $Computername | ft Name,ID,VirtualMemorySize64,PeakVirtualMemorySize64,WorkingSet64,PeakWorkingSet64
```

Your bitness check should be removed and you should only used the 64-bit properties.  The old properties are obselete. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..But i know the difference between 32 bit and 64 bit integer and i have taken care of the same initially then only i am running thi command.

Comment: That's not the clearest comment.  What do you mean when you say you've "taken care of the same initially"?  Did you change the `AliasProperties` to refer to the 64-bit versions of the properties?  Perhaps the way that you "took care of the same initially" is what is causing the negative numbers -- would you like to share?

Comment: Can you entertain me and let me know if retrieving the 64-bit properties returns the same negative numbers?

Comment: Nops not at all..If it is so then I must have asked the question about 64 bit architecture not about remote system..