# Powershell 3.0 Get-Process sometimes returns negative values for memory on a process?

Tags: powershell, memory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am curious how this can happen ?
my command was only

```
get-process
```

the process is running and consuming some memory for sure, but why can WS(K) and VM(M) have negative values? (btw. I don't know exactly what WS and VM stands for)
I am using PowerShell 3.0

since I run a powershell script which checks the values and reports me if the value is below 0, I now get a mail because it's below 0 :)

How can I convert that into the value, no matter if it is negative or positive?

[image: negative values]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get-process command giving negative value while monitoring process on a remote computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933617/get-process-command-giving-negative-value-while-monitoring-process-on-a-remote-c)

Comment: WS(K) = Working Set in Kb. Essentially the amount physical memory in use by the process. 
VM(M) = Virtual Memory in Mb. Amount of virtual memory allocated to the process.

Comment: More info on process properties: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some background on this [here](http://tfl09.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/get-process-produces-negative-numbers.html) but essentially this is PowerShell (or something deeper) getting mixed up between 32-bit/64-bit and signed/unsigned numbers.

If I run a `get-process DBPROCESS` on a 64-bit server that has some hefty database processes, I can see some negative numbers e.g.

```
. Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
. -------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
.   19357     348  -297416    -581352    34 5,407.32   6012 DBPROCESS
```

I'm going to look at the WS(K) - WorkingSet number.

Re-running the command below shows that there are additional 64-bit properties representing the same parameters:

```
get-process DBPROCESS | select-object -property working* | fl
WorkingSet   : -595304448
WorkingSet64 : 3699662848
```

The value for WorkingSet corresponeds to the WS(K) column multiplied by 1024

i.e. -581385 x 1024 = -595304448

We can see though, that WorkingSet64 is a much bigger number - far greater than the largest +ve number that a 32-bit signed integer can represent (2,147,483,647).

The binary representation for 3699662848 (according to Windows calculator) is (11011100 10000100 01100000 00000000) - only 32 bits, but crucially, the most significant (leftmost) bit is a 1.

When numbers are represented in binary, the most significant bit represents the sign. A most significant bit (MSB) of 0 means it's a positive number. Conversely, an MSB of 1 means it's a negative number.

In this example then, PowerShell (or Windows) takes the bits and interprets them as a 32-bit signed integer which (according to Windows calculator again) is -595304448.

Interestingly, if I run the `get-process` from a remote machine (Windows 7 - 64 bit), then both numbers are shown as negative. This is another question altogether I suspect...

```
WorkingSet   : -595304448
WorkingSet64 : -595304448
```